# Hidden field to hold ID value in Windows Phone 8 XAML page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I come from asp.net background, where there is a Hidden Field control to hold the value of the ID of the record loaded on the page. Is there an alternative for doing the same in a xaml page in WP8 app?

All I need is to store the ID of the record on to a control on the page when initially load the page. On an event on the page, I would like to retrieve the ID from the control and use it to query the DB.

Thanks

Comment: You can use the `Tag` property.

Comment: Thanks @Alaa Masoud, I ended up using the Tag, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the dirty way (and analogous to a Hidden Field) would be to put up a TextBlock and set Visibility to Collapsed.

The cleaner way which just works as a matter of course is by using the MVVM design pattern, in which all the data you are working with is part of a regular class. Visual controls like TextBlocks, TextBoxes, etc. are then bound to the instance of your class (aka the ViewModel / DataContext). Your ID field would be part of the view model (class), but it wouldn't have an associated visual element.

I would recommend taking just a bit of time to look at the [MVVM pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) and binding model before going too far into your Windows Phone development, it's incredibly elegant, not really that hard to get your head around (its roots are in MVC) and will save you a world of work and head banging :)

There is [a simple MVVM phone sample on the Dev Center](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Model-View-ViewModel-Sample-8cb92fd9), and [this quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207023%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) should help too.

Unfortunately, the [create your first app for Windows Phone tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402526%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) on that site doesn't touch this important concept.

Comment: But to be fair, some things like "dirty forms" shouldnt be a part of the object. But to share that information with the view, you need an associated component.